# Unity 3D text getting cut off

Tags: text, unity-game-engine

How I could fix an issue I am having with a Unity 3D project?

In the main menu, there are three options for the user to select on the side. However, when I build and run the project those 3D text object are cut off halfway by the end of the screen.

Is there is a way to somehow make the text adapt to both the resolution the user is playing in and the size of the players screen?

I want the text to look as if it has not moved on a 20" screen compared to a 16".